# How to use a configuration property in an annotation (as parameter)?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Currently I use an annotation like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "jsmdestination_01", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receive(..
```

However, I like to extract this destination value into a properties file (application.yml for example).

Normally I would use:

```
@Value("${application.queue.destination}")
private String theDestination;
```

My IDE already hints that extracting it to a class variable is even impossible, so, I'm wondering if anyone has solved this already.

Comment: By simply putting that into your `destination`. `destination="${application.queue.destination}"`. AFAIK property support has been added for that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum